# MySQL - inner join on select query error 1052

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, group-by

Im trying to do a select query on a table along with an inner join afterwards to link data from the owner to the cats

the ownercat is using a foreign key on the id linking to the ownerinfo id

```
USE CATTERY;
SELECT
OWNERINFO.ID, OWNERINFO.First_Name, OWNERINFO.Last_Name, OWNERINFO.Phone, OWNERINFO.AddrL1, OWNERINFO.AddrL2, OWNERINFO.AddrL3, OWNERINFO.PostCode,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT OWNERCAT.Chip_ID)
FROM OWNERINFO
INNER JOIN OWNERCAT ON OWNERINFO.ID = OWNERCAT.ID

WHERE ID = 1;
```

I get returned the following error:
Error Code: 1052. Column 'ID' in where clause is ambiguous  0.0014 sec

removing the concat distinct statement still produces the same error, im not sure how to get around this issue

Comment: 'WHERE ID = 1;' - ID is probably ambiguous here(every other column is qualified with table name) - qualify with the table name you require,

Comment: `WHERE OWNERINFO.ID = 1`

Comment: AHHH, i see what you mean, I assumed it would have understood this but i assumed wrong. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define from which table the `ID` on `WHERE`-clause come from (you can use aliases). Secondly, as you are using `GROUP_CONCAT`, you should have `GROUP BY` in the query:

```
SELECT
  oi.ID, 
  oi.First_Name, 
  oi.Last_Name, 
  oi.Phone, 
  oi.AddrL1, 
  oi.AddrL2, 
  oi.AddrL3, 
  oi.PostCode,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT oc.Chip_ID)
FROM OWNERINFO oi
  INNER JOIN OWNERCAT oc ON oc.ID=oi.ID
WHERE oi.ID = 1
GROUP BY oi.ID
```

Comment: Yeah i see that, but when i am trying to use the where clause at the bottom regarding the ID number it produces an error

Comment: Forgot the `WHERE`-clause. Added now.

Comment: Ah, i understand, the where clause must be before the group, thank you i appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `WHERE` clause: `ID` is ambiguous, because that column is available in both tables.

You may think that, since you are joining the tables on `ID`, the database is able to tell that it has the same value, but that's not actually the case.

So just qualify the column in the `WHERE` clause, ie change this:

```
WHERE ID = 1
```

To either:

```
WHERE OWNERINFO.ID = 1
```

Or the equivalent:

```
WHERE OWNERCAT.ID = 1
```

Also please note that your query uses `GROUP_CONCAT()`, which is an aggregate function. This implies that you need a `GROUP BY` clause, that should list all non-aggregated column (ie *all* columns other than the one that is within `GROUP_CONCAT()`).